# How to change individual color depending on bool value - Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, key

I want to to change the color of a `container` depending on the value of the boolean I have saved. but when I change the color of the container it changes all the container's color because my code is referring to all the containers, so how would I be able to just make one container's color change
Here is my code and some extra info:

```
joined = false;

//when I click on a button it changes the value to true

...onPressed: (){Joined = true;}

//when Joined is true it should change the color to green

color: Joined ? Colors.blue : Colors.green),

//I also gave each container a key/id
//This is referencing a Firebase Database

People['key'] = snapshot.value;

//but when I write this code it makes ALL the container's colors green
//I have all the tools I just don't know how to write the code.
```

I tried to implement the `People['key']` code when changing the value but it didn't work and I wasn't really sure how to write the code. I also tried researching on YouTube and Google but there weren't really a lot of info to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map,

```
Map<String. bool> joined = {};
    
...onPressed: (){joined[id] = true;}

color: (joined.containskey(id) && joined[id]) ? Colors.blue : Colors.green),
```